# Smarter way to getElementsByClassName with function

Tags: javascript, css, function, getelementsbyclassname

I was wondering if there isn't a smarter way to work with classes between javascript and css. As I understander the "only" / most common way to select all elements with the same class is by making a for loop:
[jsfiddle.net/JoshuaChronstedt/obk92sh6/2/](http://jsfiddle.net/JoshuaChronstedt/obk92sh6/2/)

```
var elems = document.getElementsByClassName("helloClass");

for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
   elems[i].style.background = "red";
}
```

Wouldn't it be possible to create a function to hold the for loop? I'm a noob to js and can't seem to make it work:
[jsfiddle.net/JoshuaChronstedt/obk92sh6/6/](http://jsfiddle.net/JoshuaChronstedt/obk92sh6/4/)

```
function getClass(getClassName) {
    var elems = document.getElementsByClassName("getClassName");
    for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
        elems[i];
    }
}

getClass("helloClass").style.background = "red";

getClass("helloClassTwo").style.background = "blue";
```

I guess what I am ultimately trying to do is find a more readable and more DRY way of editing elements by class names.
edit:
Thanks for the snippets. I have tried using some of the code that has been sugested. But it still doesn't seem to work:

```js
function getClass(getClassName) {
  Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.' + '\'' + getClassName + '\'')).forEach(e => e);
}

getClass(helloClass).style.background = 'yellow';

getClass(helloClassTwo).style.color = 'red';
```

```html
<div class="helloClass">
  hello class
</div>

<div class="helloClass">
  hello class
</div>


<div class="helloClassTwo">
  hello class Two
</div>

<div class="helloClassTwo">
  hello class Two
</div>
```

Comment: You're passing `getClassName` as a quoted string, rather than the parameter given to the function. Take those double quotes away, and I suspect you'll be good to go. Also look at jQuery if you haven't already!

Comment: Do you consider [`Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.helloClass')).forEach(e => e.style.background = 'green');`](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/obk92sh6/5/) _smarter_?

Comment: @CameronHurd ok, yeah I can see that getClassName turns blue in the editor. But the code still doesn't seem to work: [link]http://jsfiddle.net/JoshuaChronstedt/obk92sh6/6/

Comment: @Tushar Yes that is definitely much smarter than the for loop. Thanks alot. But it still doesn't solve the problem of putting the selector into a function. I guss what I am trying to do is create a more Don't-Repeat-Yourself solution to the problem of selecting classes with javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement `map` function to iterate.`map` function iterates elements in array.
Hence here you need to change normal object to array first using `Array.from()` method

```
var elems;

function getClass(getClassfuncCont) {
   return document.getElementsByClassName(getClassfuncCont);
}

elems = getClass("helloClass");
Array.from(elems).map(element=>element.style.background = "red");
```

Please refer working snippet.

```js
  var elems;

function getClass(getClassfuncCont) {
   return document.getElementsByClassName(getClassfuncCont);
}

elems = getClass("helloClass");
Array.from(elems).map(element=>element.style.background = "red");
```

```html
<div class="helloClass">
  hello class
</div>

<div class="helloClass">
  hello class
</div>

<div class="helloClass">
  hello class
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @Dhirak, I am too noob to figure out if this is actually a more DRY way of selecting classes with JavaScript? Seems like you have to repeat all of this every time you need to select a class: `code` elems = getClass("helloClass");
Array.from(elems).map(element=>element.style.background = "red");

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in one of the comments, you're passing `getClassName` as string when you're supposed to pass it as variable. Taking away the double quote should make it work.

However, you won't be able to modify the style property the way you're doing it right now, because your function does not return the elements. If what you're trying to do is batch-changing the background color based on class name, I suggest adding the color name as a second variable:

```
 //renaming the function so it's more representative
   function colorBackgroundByClass(getClassName,color) {
        var elems = document.getElementsByClassName(getClassName);
        for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
            elems[i].style.background = color;
        }
    }

    colorBackgroundByClass("helloClass","red");

    colorBackgroundByClass("helloClassTwo","blue");
```

Comment: Thanks atnatn, how would you go about making it flexible so you can use it for any style property? Hence a more DRY way of selecting classes in genneral.

Comment: actually i think you can pass a function as a second variable, like `function getClass(getClassName,modifyFunction)`, then run it inside the function `modifyFunction(elems[i])`

and then you can call
`getClass("helloClass",function(param){
   param.style.background = "red";
})`